# React useEffect not running on dependency change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, client

#### What I am trying to do

I have a lobby that users can join. To persist the joined lobby on the client on a page refresh I decided to put the lobby that has been joined into the browser's session storage. Before it was just in a `useState` which doesn't persist through a page refresh.

Setting Session Storage is classified as a side effect as far as I know and should be handled in `useEffect`. The problem is when I set the lobby the `useEffect` that has the lobby as a dependency doesn't run.

Setting breakpoints shows that it doesn't run at all, but I can see that the `joinedLobby` has changed from `undefined` to an object (example : `{success: "Successfully joined ...", payload : { id:"", ...}}`).

The session store stays empty.

### Code Sandbox

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-swirles-084o6?file=/src/NewLobby.jsx)
CSS is broken since I was using Emotion

## Update

Fetching Data from the back end breaks the app. Making the data static made the app function like it should.

I have 0 ideas on why / how. The culprit seems to be play_index.jsx at line 165 `const jsonResponse`.

#### Setting the state that should update the useEffect

```js
  const { setJoinedLobby } = useContext(JoinedLobbyProviderContext);
  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (joinState.result === undefined) return;
    setJoinedLobby(joinState.result);
    history.push('/lobby');
  }, [joinState.result, history, setJoinedLobby]);
```

#### Provider inside router

```js
          <JoinedLobbyProviderContext.Provider
            value={{ getJoinedLobby, setJoinedLobby }}>
            <Route path='/play'>
              <Play />
            </Route>
            <Route path='/lobby'>
              <Lobby />
            </Route>
          </JoinedLobbyProviderContext.Provider>
```

#### The functions the provider takes

```js
  const [joinedLobby, setJoinedLobby] = useState(undefined);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (joinedLobby === undefined) return;
    sessionStorage.setItem('joinedLobby', JSON.stringify(joinedLobby));
  }, [joinedLobby]);

  const getJoinedLobby = () => {
    return JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('joinedLobby'));
  };
```

#### Edit : How joinState.result changes

```js
const joinInit = {
    errors: undefined,
    loading: false,
    result: undefined,
    id: undefined,
  };

  const joinReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'joinLobby': {
        return { ...state, id: action.payload };
      }
      case 'loadingTrue':
        return { ...state, loading: true };
      case 'setResult':
        return { ...state, loading: false, result: action.payload };
      case 'setErrors':
        return {
          ...state,
          loading: false,
          errors: action.payload,
        };
      case 'reset':
        return joinInit;
      default : {throw new Error('Didn't find action passed to reducer')}
    }
  };

  const [joinState, joinStateDispatch] = useReducer(joinReducer, joinInit);

  const passRef = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    const joinLobby = async () => {
      joinStateDispatch({ type: 'loadingTrue' });
      try {
        const jsonResponse = await (
          await fetch(`${BACKEND_URL}/play/joinLobby/${joinState.id}`, {
            method: 'PATCH',
            credentials: 'include',
            headers: {
              'Content-type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              password: passRef.current.value,
            }),
          })
        ).json();
        joinStateDispatch({ type: 'setResult', payload: jsonResponse });
      } catch (e) {
        joinStateDispatch({ type: 'setErrors', payload: e });
      }
    };
    if (joinState.id !== undefined) {
      joinLobby();
    }
  }, [joinState.id, joinStateDispatch]);
```

Comment: Can you show, how do you call and update joinedLobby with setJoinedLobby

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri first code block `setJoinedLobby(joinState.result)`.

Comment: how will `joinState.result`change

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri  I edited the question to include how joinState changes.

 
joinState changes as expected, and when I pause on the third code block I can see that the joinState is set to the proper object, but useEffect has not fired despite the change.

Comment: There is nothing in the code that you provided that comes out as an obvious flaw to me :-(. Could you create a reproducible demo  on codesandbox so that people can check that and help you out

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri yea I am on that right now. I need to decouple it from the backend which is a pain

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri added the sandbox